# How is に being used in これよつばがつかまえに?

Tags: particle-に

I'm reading Yotsuba and I came across this sentence, これよつばがつかまえに. They have the english translation as, "This is the one I caught." My question is why is に used here instead of つかまえた? In the picture that goes along with the sentence, she is pointing at the bug she caught. Could this be a target marker and the use of いる was omitted since これ was used? If so, why is the verb stem of つかまえる used here with に? The only other time I have seen a verb stem and に used together is when you go somewhere and state a purpose for doing so. I don't think that reason would apply here although I could be wrong.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it's not た in the original text? た and に look somewhat similar.

Comment: No It's definitely に

Comment: Um, so I went and looked for the raws for this manga and found a different version of [this page](https://i.imgur.com/lRNbdb2.jpg]). The link @l'électeur provided looks like it was typeset differently to this one (using a different font). If I had to guess, the version with に is a typo when it was typeset differently, but I'm not certain.

Comment: On closer inspection of that page, it looks like whoever created the page had to manually type the script line by line, so I'm thinking that it was indeed a typo. The pictures on that page are cleaned of text and then there's both an English and Japanese script (that must have been manually typed) overlayed on the cleaned images. You can [inspect element](https://i.imgur.com/mfxI5vA.png) to see this.

Comment: Yeah, it appears to be a transcription error. I own volume 1 so I can confirm the raw snippet posted by @ZLK: https://i.imgur.com/JXPvQli.jpg

Comment: Thanks for the help @ZLK